# How do I apply multiple id's to one record in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans, mysql-workbench

I did a database for my eCommerce using MySQL Workbench and I'm using Netbeans to put everything together. I have few tables that serve the purpose of what I'm trying to achieve. Two of these tables that are connected together are *product* and of course *category*.

I'm at the point of adding data into both tables. Each *category* has its own *category_id* obviously.

**The issue:** one single product can be in multiple categories (therefor have multiple *category_id* but I don't know how to do that because Netbeans only seem to allow one *category_id* per product whether I use a command line or do it manually.

[image]

[image]

As you can see on the pictures, the product named *mac* is set to technology for home which category_id is 208. But the same product could also be part of 209 (technology for office).

How do I go about achieving that? Do I need to enter a new row for the same product every time I need a product to be part of multiple categories? Let's say if a product can be part of 3 categories, do I need to enter 3 records? Is there another way of doing so because to the knowledge I have, that would be very long and exhausting, no?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a many-to-many relationship in the entity-relationship lingo. A product can have multiple categories, and a category can have multiple products.

To do this in a relational database, you need **three** tables.

```
product:  product_id, name, description, etc
category: category_id, catname, catdescription, etc
```

And then this so-called *join table* to establish the relationships between products and categories.

```
product_category:  product_id, category_id
```

The primary key of product_category is both columns together -- it's a compound primary key.

If you have these products

```
1 chromebook
2 minitower
3 macbook
4 laptop
```

and these categories

```
1 chromeos
2 portable
3 windows 7
4 macos
```

You then will have these entries in your product_category table

```
1  1   chromebook categories: ... chromeos
1  2                          ... portable
2  3   minitower category     ... windows 7
3  2   macbook categories     ... portable
3  4                          ... macos
4  2   laptop categories      ... portable
4  3                          ... windows 7
```

So, if you want to see the categories for each product, you can do

```
 SELECT name, description,
        GROUP_CONCAT(catname) categories
   FROM product
   JOIN product_category USING (product_id)
   JOIN category USING (category_id)
```

Likewise, if you want all the laptops you can do this.

```
 SELECT name, description
   FROM product
   JOIN product_category USING (product_id)
   JOIN category USING (category_id)
  WHERE catname = 'laptop'
```

If you want all the macos laptop devices, it's a little more complex.

```
 SELECT name, description
   FROM product p
   JOIN product_category pca ON p.product_id = pca.product_id
   JOIN category ca   ON pca.product_id = ca.product_id
                     AND ca.catname = 'macos'
   JOIN product_category pcb ON p.product_id = pcb.product_id
   JOIN category ca   ON pcb.product_id = cb.product_id
                     AND cb.catname = 'laptop'
```

Notice that the composite primary key prevents you from assigning a product more than once to a category and vice versa.

Pro tip:  For clarity it's a good idea to use the same column name in all your tables for the values on which you join. For example, the `product_id` shows up in both the `product` and `product_category` table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your constructed answer. I have just created a 3rd table in Workbench using the database. Following your advice I should make an arrow from category to the 3rd table and an arrow from product to the 3rd table is that? Or the arrow from the 3rd to product and category?

Comment: The copy of MySQL Workbench I have offers a n::m item (Place a new n:m identifying relationship) on the right of the "diagram" drawing panel.  If you click that, then click your product table, then click your category table, the Workbench will make you a join table. It will call it "product_has_category", but you can change its name to "product_category".

Answer (score 1):

You can use another table to achieve this.  Name it something like `categories_products`.  It should have three columns

```
id
category_id
product_id
```

Then have entries for each category a product is in, like:

```
id=1,
category_id=208,
product_id=1
```

and

```
id=2,
category_id=209,
product_id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to research the [Many to Many Data Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model))

In theory you could create a table for products, a table for categories, and a table to link the two. This would allow for a virtually infinite number of categories that a single product could be linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Using table structure you have it is not possible.

The best option is storing comma-separated string in category_field and handle it in your application making one more query

The second option is creation of new table with two columns `group_categoy_id` and `category_id` and use `group_category_id` in your product table instead of `category_id`. In this case you can have endless group of categories, and you need only one query to get all data you need.